# Get Birthdays of all Users from User Profile Services Rest API

Tags: user-profile-service, sharepoint-rest-api

Among all the endpoints i have seen for user profile service, i dont see any such endpoint which gives birthday property of user.

I need to get for all users at once. Is it Possible?

Comment: Have you tried any option? Any luck?

Comment: Well, i can get the birthday property from User Profile API, but there was no information, so i had to store it in a list

Answer (score 0):

It is not an endpoint, but the `SPS-Birthday` property

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=SPS-Birthday